# Using TryUpdateModelAsync with an IEnumerable Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Model:

```
public class InvoiceCategory
{     
    [Key]
    public int InvoiceCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Edit Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(IEnumerable<InvoiceCategory> invoiceCategories)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var categoryToUpdate = await _context.InvoiceCategory.ToListAsync(); 

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<InvoiceCategory>(
               categoryToUpdate,
               "",
               i => i.InvoiceCategories)) /// <-- This is incorrect
            {

            }

             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         ...
        }           
    }

    return View();
}
```

How can you use TryUpdateModelAsync to update an IEnumerable collection?

Or is there a better way to update it?

Comment: if i understad correctly you want to update the collection using TryUpdateModelAsync. or only single category ?

Comment: Yes thats correct i want to update the entire collection using tryupdatemodel or similar method that takes advantage of model binding.